# Greek characters - phpMyAdmin

Tags: android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I send some data (utf8) in my dataBase and I'm seeing them from phpMyAdmin. The data contains greek and english characters. The problem is that greek characters are showing up as question marks(????). The english are ok. No matter what I have tried:

For dataBase and my column collation: utf8_unicode_ci, utf8_general_ci

After my connection with dataBase:

```
mysqli_query ("SET NAMES 'UTF8'", $dbc);
mysqli_query ("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'", $dbc);
```

the problem still remains and I can't figure out how to solve it. Does somebody knows how to fix that?

Update:
    The data are sent from an Android application:

```
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a", "hello, ΓΕΙΑ ΣΟΥ" ));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("b", "Good Morning, ΚΑΛΗΜΕΡΑ"));              
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    try {
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
}
```

And the command to insert values into database:

```
$q= 'INSERT INTO `table`(`x`, `y`) VALUES ("'.$_POST["a"].'","'.$_POST["b"].'")';
```

Comment: Can we also see some PHP code? Maybe the problem is where you send the data into the database.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos Of course, wait a minute, I will post some code.

Comment: How does android tag apply? Are you browsing that site on android? Check also the encoding of the fields in the table!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that your db has UTF8 encoding enabled for the db/tables
2. Check on browser that UTF8 is enabled (e.g. for Firefox: View/Character Encoding/Unicode (UTF-8))
3. Check reponse Content-type http header:
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

This is a FAQ so the phpMyAdmin team has written this page to help: 
http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I searched and read this post.
After I have found a solution to my problem I want to share it.

change this line of your code

```
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

to

```
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
```

and now you are ok.

Answer (score 0):

George, at first I thought that your code was in PHP, taking into consideration that you mentioned phpMyAdmin. Although, I do have a little experience in Android, and I would avoid writing Greek characters (or any non-standard characters) in a `.java` file.

Instead, you should use the `strings.xml` file that Android supports, and access your strings in the code like this:

```
R.string.kalimera
```

where `kalimera` is the name of the variable you use for your "Hello" text.

That would perfectly explain why the database is filled with question-marks (????) instead of the actual characters (or at least so I think).